# T/F: If $f$ is even, then its Taylor polynomial of order $n$ (if exists, and for every $n$) is also even.

Tags: calculus

T/F: If $f$ is even, then its Taylor polynomial of order $n$ (if exists, and for every $n$) is also even.

I tried to assume by contradiction that there exists $n$ such that the Taylor polynomial of $f$ is not even, and then there's a sentence that a
says that $f(x) = P_{n}(x) + R_{n}(x)$. But now I don't know how to continue.

Can I get some directions?

Comment: Hint: Sum of two odd functions can be even.

Comment: Interestingly, perhaps, the converse is false. The Maclaurin polynomials of $f(x)$ can be all even, while $f$ is not.

Comment: @Andre Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Let $f(x)=0$ if $x\le 0$, and $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ for $x\gt 0$. Then all the Maclaurin polynomials are identically $0$.  (The Maclaurin series for $f(x)$ only converges to $f(x)$ at $x=0$.)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean the Maclaurin series; the claim is clearly false for arbitrary Taylor series.

This is true by symmetry: Forming the Maclaurin series and reflecting at the origin commute; since reflecting $f$ leaves it invariant, it follows that reflecting the Maclaurin series also leaves it invariant.

Comment: No... I meant Taylor series

Comment: @EricaJ.: Then take the Taylor polynomial of $f(x)=x^2$ at $x_0=1$ for $n=1$. This is $2(x-1)$, which isn't even.

Answer (score 1):

(I assume the Taylor polynomial is taken at $x_0=0$, otherwise I'm almost certain it is false)

The derivative of an even function is an odd function, and the derivative of an odd function is an even function. Odd function vanish at $0$, so the coefficients of odd degrees will also vanish at $0$.

Comment: They don't tell me which $x_{0}$

Answer (score 0):

Hinting: As you wrote, you have

$$f(x)=P_n(x)+R_n(x), \;\;\text{and thus}\;\;f(-x)=P_n(-x)+R_n(-x)$$

But you know that $\;f(x)=f(-x)\;$ , so...what? Observe that you can do this for $\;n=1,2,...$

Following the other comments-answers: I assumed from the question itself that you were talking of a Maclaurin series.

Comment: I meant Taylor series...

Comment: Erica, if you meant a general Taylor series around an arbitrary point then the claim is, I think, false. Around zero it is true.